# Mixture prior with Turing.jl

Tags: statistics, julia, bayesian

I am trying to write a model with a mixture prior on one of the parameters. However I run into `TypeError: in typeassert, expected Float64, got a value of type ForwardDiff.Dual{Nothing, Float64, 2}`

In Stan it's possible to write this type of prior by incrementing the target with the logsumexp of each of the mixture densities. Is that the way to handle this in Turing.jl also?

A simplified version of my model and inference code:

```
using Random
using Turing

Random.seed!(42);

x = randn(2000);

@model function model(x)
    s ~ InverseGamma(2, 3)
    mean = [0, 0]
    sd = [0.0309, 0.3479]
    mix = [0.9736, 0.0264]
    k = 2
    m ~ MixtureModel(
        Normal,
        [(mean[j], sd[j]) for j = 1:k],
        mix
    )

    for i = 1:length(x)
        x[i] ~ Normal(m, sqrt(s))
    end
end;

m = model(x);
samples_nuts = sample(m, NUTS(200, 0.65), 10_000);
```

The start of the stack trace is

```
ERROR: TypeError: in typeassert, expected Float64, got a value of type ForwardDiff.Dual{Nothing, Float64, 2}
Stacktrace:
  [1] setindex!(A::Vector{Float64}, x::ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{Turing.Core.var"#f#7"{DynamicPPL.TypedVarInfo{NamedTuple{(:s, :m), Tuple{DynamicPPL.Metadata{Dict{AbstractPPL.VarName{:s, Tuple{}}, Int64}, Vector{InverseGamma{Float64}}, Vector{AbstractPPL.VarName{:s, Tuple{}}}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Set{DynamicPPL.Selector}}}, DynamicPPL.Metadata{Dict{AbstractPPL.VarName{:m, Tuple{}}, Int64}, Vector{MixtureModel{Univariate, Continuous, Normal, Float64}}, Vector{AbstractPPL.VarName{:m, Tuple{}}}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Set{DynamicPPL.Selector}}}}}, Float64}, DynamicPPL.Model{var"#7#10", (:x,), (), (), Tuple{Vector{Float64}}, Tuple{}}, DynamicPPL.Sampler{NUTS{Turing.Core.ForwardDiffAD{40}, (), AdvancedHMC.DiagEuclideanMetric}}, DynamicPPL.DefaultContext}, Float64}, Float64, 2}, i1::Int64)
    @ Base ./array.jl:903
  [2] _mixlogpdf1(d::MixtureModel{Univariate, Continuous, Normal, Float64}, x::ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{Turing.Core.var"#f#7"{DynamicPPL.TypedVarInfo{NamedTuple{(:s, :m), Tuple{DynamicPPL.Metadata{Dict{AbstractPPL.VarName{:s, Tuple{}}, Int64}, Vector{InverseGamma{Float64}}, Vector{AbstractPPL.VarName{:s, Tuple{}}}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Set{DynamicPPL.Selector}}}, DynamicPPL.Metadata{Dict{AbstractPPL.VarName{:m, Tuple{}}, Int64}, Vector{MixtureModel{Univariate, Continuous, Normal, Float64}}, Vector{AbstractPPL.VarName{:m, Tuple{}}}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Set{DynamicPPL.Selector}}}}}, Float64}, DynamicPPL.Model{var"#7#10", (:x,), (), (), Tuple{Vector{Float64}}, Tuple{}}, DynamicPPL.Sampler{NUTS{Turing.Core.ForwardDiffAD{40}, (), AdvancedHMC.DiagEuclideanMetric}}, DynamicPPL.DefaultContext}, Float64}, Float64, 2})
    @ Distributions ~/.julia/packages/Distributions/HjzA0/src/mixtures/mixturemodel.jl:358
  [3] logpdf_with_trans(d::MixtureModel{Univariate, Continuous, Normal, Float64}, x::ForwardDiff.Dual{ForwardDiff.Tag{Turing.Core.var"#f#7"{DynamicPPL.TypedVarInfo{NamedTuple{(:s, :m), Tuple{DynamicPPL.Metadata{Dict{AbstractPPL.VarName{:s, Tuple{}}, Int64}, Vector{InverseGamma{Float64}}, Vector{AbstractPPL.VarName{:s, Tuple{}}}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Set{DynamicPPL.Selector}}}, DynamicPPL.Metadata{Dict{AbstractPPL.VarName{:m, Tuple{}}, Int64}, Vector{MixtureModel{Univariate, Continuous, Normal, Float64}}, Vector{AbstractPPL.VarName{:m, Tuple{}}}, Vector{Float64}, Vector{Set{DynamicPPL.Selector}}}}}, Float64}, DynamicPPL.Model{var"#7#10", (:x,), (), (), Tuple{Vector{Float64}}, Tuple{}}, DynamicPPL.Sampler{NUTS{Turing.Core.ForwardDiffAD{40}, (), AdvancedHMC.DiagEuclideanMetric}}, DynamicPPL.DefaultContext}, Float64}, Float64, 2}, transform::Bool)
    @ Bijectors ~/.julia/packages/Bijectors/3suua/src/Bijectors.jl:0
  [4] assume
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Turing/uAz5c/src/inference/hmc.jl:529 [inlined]
  [5] _tilde
    @ ~/.julia/packages/DynamicPPL/SgzCy/src/context_implementations.jl:62 [inlined]
```

pkg status

```
  [523fee87] CodecBzip2 v0.7.2
  [1624bea9] ConjugatePriors v0.4.0
  [b964fa9f] LaTeXStrings v1.3.0
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.25.5
  [df47a6cb] RData v0.8.3
  [f3b207a7] StatsPlots v0.14.30
  [fce5fe82] Turing v0.15.1
```

Comment: Could you paste the full stack trace of the error? That would help narrow down where it's originating from.

Comment: The stack trace is 85 lines long so no, but I've added the start

Comment: I don't get an error on Turing master. Can you add the specific versions of Turing, Distributions, and DistributionsAD, and ForwardDiff from `Pkg.status()`, please?

Comment: @phipsgabler done

Comment: OK, v0.15 is quite old. Can you update Turing and try again?

Comment: @phibsgabler It's the version I got by installing through standard Julia channels, but sure I'll do my best to update from github I guess

Comment: Indeed, works on current master